# Click and Drop down values by using list/string

Tags: java, katalon-studio

I have set of Array values and need to click on the dropdown object by using them, how to do this in proper way?.

My XPath is `"//li[@class="header__country-selector--desktop__country"]//a[contains(text()," + **ARRAY VALUES** +")]"`

My code :

Custom keyword:

```
public class selectCountry {

    private String Market_selector(String nav_id){

        return '//li[@class="header__country-selector--desktop__country"]//a[contains(text()," +Countries+")]'


        //      //li[@class="header__country-selector--desktop__country"]//a[contains(text(),'')]
    }

    private TestObject getHeadernavMenuTestObject(String nav_id){
        TestObject navitem = new TestObject(nav_id)
        navitem.addProperty("xpath", ConditionType.EQUALS, Market_selector(nav_id), true)
        return navitem
    }

    @Keyword
    public void getMarket_selector(String nav_id){
        TestObject navitem = getHeadernavMenuTestObject(nav_id);
        WebUI.waitForElementPresent(navitem,GlobalVariable.load_time)
        WebUI.verifyElementPresent(navitem, GlobalVariable.load_time, FailureHandling.CONTINUE_ON_FAILURE);
        WebUI.focus(navitem)
        WebUI.click(navitem)
    }
```

Array

```
String[] Countries = ['UAE','Bahrain','Oman','Qatar','Kuwait','Egypt','Jordan','Tunisia','Morocco','Palestine','Iraq'];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your xpath should be

```
"//li[@class="header__country-selector--desktop__country"]//a[contains(text()," + countries[${i}] +")]"
```

Where `i` is the index of `countries[]` (also note `countries` is lowercase, as per convention).

Then loop through the list:

```
for (def i=0; i<countries.size(); i++){
    getMarket_selector(Market_selector(i.toString()))
}
```

Comment: if I need to select those countries by the loop (for) where to put that (keyword / in the test case)? would be better if I can get an example